# Powershell: Call one remote script from another remote script

Tags: powershell, remote

I inherited some code where one script references another like this:

```
#Script1.ps1
param($arg1)

# do some stuff

# call script2 with argument from script1
.\script2.ps1 $arg1


#script2.ps1
param($arg1)
# do some stuff unique to this script
```

This works fine locally, but when both scripts are deployed to remote server, and script1 is called via invoke-command, the remote PS instance complains that it can't find script2:

```
invoke-command $remoteServer { param($arg1, $remoteScript) powershell $remoteScript $arg1 } -argumentList $arg1, $remoteScript
# output from script1
# more output from script 1    
# here comes the error when script1 calls script2:
The term '.\script2.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, functi

on, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a p

ath was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Script2 is used by a number of other scripts (successfully on the local environment) so I can't refactor script2 back into script1.

So, how can I tell script1 to call script2 in a manner that will work whether the script is run locally or on a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this works:

```
# script1.ps1

# do stuff

# get the current folder
$currentFolder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# call the second script in the remote folder with arguments from the first
. (Join-Path $currentFolder script2.ps1) $arg1
```